# Is there a java script code to animate vertical black bars with certain width to move over white background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a java script code to animate vertical black bars with certain width to move over white background ?
I want the finish result to be like in this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdMWbfTMOMM
Thank you

Comment: How are you willing to accomplish this? `<svg>`? `<div>`?  `<canvas>`?

Comment: @Rojo I would prefer using div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using `<canvas>` for animations. It's easy to use if you're good with JS.

I'm kind of hoping you know something about `<canvas>` and using it with JS. Here is something to get you started:

```js
var $c = $('.canvas');
var ctx = $c[0].getContext('2d');
var x = [0, 40, 80, 120, 160, 200, 240, 280, 320, 360, 400];

setInterval(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
  var out = x.indexOf(401);
  if (out !== -1) {
    x[out] = -40;
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(x[i], 0, 20, 200);
    x[i]++;
  }
}, 20);
```

```css
.canvas {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arv/ExplorerCanvas/master/excanvas.js'></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<canvas class='canvas' width='400px' height='200px'>Eeek canvas not supported</canvas>
```

This code is really simple... If you an idea of how `<canvas>` works, then this code shouldn't be hard to understand.

> This code uses JQuery if you didn't notice. It can be modified to not use JQuery easily.

Let me know if you want an explanation of this code.

Comment: Woow , dear Rojo. This is great.Exactly what i want. Thank you :)

Comment: Is there a way for this code to work on IE11 ?

Comment: Unfortunately. It seems that IE11 not supports canvas

Comment: @EgyEast I added IE support - `<script src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arv/ExplorerCanvas/master/excanvas.js'></script>` That should work...

Comment: @EgyEast see https://github.com/arv/ExplorerCanvas for better IE `<canvas>` support :)

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}
When running from IE11

Comment: The examples on your link works great on IE 11. However, I cannot apply your code to work on these examples.

Comment: Hi @Rojo Please could you help me with this error that appear when trying code on IE11 even from Code Snippet (https://ibb.co/DQfP7gX)